# How is it possible to upload static files (image, documents)?

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I have just finished the tutorial of channels and straggled to write codes for uploading static files for almost a week. Could you help me to write both js and consumer.py? Thank you in advance.

I especially do not understand:

1. how to write js to send static data to consumer.py
2. how to get static data in consumer.py from js.

My codes are:

```
js
<script>

   var obj = document.getElementById('talk_element');
            obj.scrollTop = obj.scrollHeight;

    var roomName = {{ room.pk }};

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/room/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        var file = data['file'];
        var created_by = data['created_by']

        var user = `{{ user }}`;

        if (created_by == user) {
            document.getElementById('talk_element').innerHTML += `
            <li class="container card-text text-right text-black">
                <span class="speech-bubble-user text-left">${message}</span>
                <img src="${file}" max-width="350" height=auto/>
             </li>`;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('talk_element').innerHTML += `
            <li class="container card-text text-left text-black">
                <span class="container speech-bubble text-left">${message}</span>
             </li>`;
            }
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        var userInputDom = document.querySelector('#creat_by');
        var user = userInputDom.value;
        var fileInputDom = document.querySelector('#document');
        var file = fileInputDom.value;

        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'created_by':user,
        }), file );

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };




</script>
```

```
consumer.py

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_pk']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data=None):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        created_by = text_data_json['created_by']
        file = text_data_json['created_by']
        room = Room.objects.get(pk=self.room_name)
        talk = Talk.objects.create(
            room=room,
            message=message,
            created_by=self.user,
            date=timezone.now
        )



        # Send message to room group

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'created_by':created_by
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message'] 
        created_by = event['created_by']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'created_by':created_by
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both JavaScript and Python to communicate properly you need to run a [WebSocket server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers). For instances, you can build one using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) or use [this one](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server).

Once you have one in place, a few things you need to do in the [client side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications):

1. Instantiate a WebSocket object to establish a connection

   ```
   var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://www.example.com/socketserver");
   ```
2. Send data (as string, Blob or ArrayBudder) to the server like this

   ```
   exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
      exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!"); 
   };
   ```

   If you want to transmit objects, then consider using JSON

   ```
   function sendText() {
       // Construct a msg object containing the data the server needs to process the message.
       var msg = {
           type: "message",
           text: document.getElementById("text").value,
           id:   clientID,
           date: Date.now()
       };

      // Send the msg object as a JSON-formatted string.
      exampleSocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
   }
   ```
3. Receive messages from the server

   ```
   exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
       console.log(event.data);
   }
   ```

   If you sent a JSON object, the code that interpretes the message might look like this

   ```
   exampleSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
       var f = document.getElementById("chatbox").contentDocument;
       var text = "";
       var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
       var time = new Date(msg.date);
       var timeStr = time.toLocaleTimeString();

       switch(msg.type) {
           case "id":
               clientID = msg.id;
               setUsername();
               break;
           case "username":
               text = "<b>User <em>" + msg.name + "</em> signed in at " + timeStr + "</b><br>";
               break;
           case "message":
               text = "(" + timeStr + ") <b>" + msg.name + "</b>: " + msg.text + "<br>";
               break;
           case "rejectusername":
               text = "<b>Your username has been set to <em>" + msg.name + "</em> because the name you chose is in use.</b><br>"
               break;
           case "userlist":
               var ul = "";
               for (i=0; i < msg.users.length; i++) {
                   ul += msg.users[i] + "<br>";
               }
               document.getElementById("userlistbox").innerHTML = ul;
               break;
        }

        if (text.length) {
            f.write(text);
            document.getElementById("chatbox").contentWindow.scrollByPages(1);
        }
   };
   ```
4. Close the connection

   ```
   exampleSocket.close();
   ```